# Android's MutableLiveData should use nullable objects only?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata, non-nullable

My simplified code is:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val myLiveData: MutableLiveData<MyObject> = MutableLiveData<MyObject>(MyObject())
    val myObject: MutableLiveData<MyObject>
        get() = myLiveData

    fun addItem(item: MyItem) {
        val value = myLiveData.value // value is of nullable type MyObject?
        // MyObject contains a list of other objects
        (value?.myList as MutableList).add(item)
        myLiveData.value = value!! // Here I get a IDE warning or error
    }
}
```

If I leave the non-null operator (!!) at line 9, Android Studio will give me a warning:

```
Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type MyObject
```

If I remove the non-null operator (!!) at line 9, Android Studio will give me an error:

```
Expected non-nullable value
```

What is the correct way to handle this in Kotlin? If I use a nullable `MyObject?` at line 2 and 3 Android Studio seems to like it, but I don't really intend for that data to be null... Is `MutableLiveData` supposed to always be nullable?

Comment: can you add code for MyItem and MyObject as well here to understand your issue properly.

Comment: If you follow the best practice then there is no use of making MutableLiveData and MutableLiveData should not hold nullable object.

Comment: You need a MutableLiveData to set values on it, and it can be nullable if that's the kind of data you want it to hold. You shouldn't *expose* it as a ``MutableLiveData`` type though - ``myObject``'s type should just be ``LiveData``

Answer (score 1):

`LiveData` is really meant to be observed - when you call `observe` on it and pass a handler function, that function will only be called when the LiveData has a value (a current one or a new one). Because your LiveData holds a non-null `MyObject` type, the observer function will only be given non-null `MyObject`s.

But if you're poking at its `value` property - that's different! Even though you're providing an initial `MyObject` value in its constructor, you don't *have* to do that - so `LiveData`s can sometimes be **empty**. If you try to observe that, the observer won't be called until a value is set. If you try to look at its `value`, it will be `null`, because there's nothing in the LiveData yet. That doesn't mean it provides nulls to observers, it's just that it doesn't have a value stored yet!

So `value` is always nullable, even if the type the `LiveData` holds is non-null. You're sort of peeking behind the scenes. You have two options really:

- use the null-safety stuff the usual way (`value?.let { ... }`) and don't worry about it, because you know there'll always be a value there, because you've set one in the constructor (this is the safest option)
- use `!!` because this seems to be one of the few situations where it's safe - you know it's not going to be null

I think the whole thing's kinda messy personally, `LiveData` has... quirks, but you're ok in this situation - I just wanted to explain what's going on!

---

Also your public type should be `LiveData<MyObject>` and not `MutableLiveData<MyObject>` - your internal copy needs to be mutable (so you can update it) but the reference you expose should be the immutable `LiveData` type instead, so users can't set it and have to go through your setter function. Just change the type:

```
val myObject: LiveData<MyObject>
        get() = myLiveData
```

and they'll see it as a standard `LiveData` they can't mess with, instead of the mutable subclass

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way around? I might be remembering wrong, but I think LiveData does not support non-nullability. Null is always accepted as a valid value that will be published to observers, so basically it doesn't know you declared the type as non-nullable, and always treats the type as nullable.

Comment: You can push a null to a non-null-type LiveData, but (in Kotlin at least) it'll crash with an ``it must not be null`` NPE - possibly when the cast to the non-null type happens. But you're right, that's not enforced at compile time or anything, and the linter doesn't care. But so long as you're using a (non-null) setter that everything has to go through, your observers shouldn't ever get a ``null`` they have to handle, even if ``value`` is null because you haven't set an initial value yet - that's what I was getting at. You can sure break it in a few interesting ways though!